# AngularJs- TypeError: Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined

Tags: html, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I want to show Google map with draggable marker in my page . Here is my code:

**header.php :**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=true"></script>
```

**map.js:**

```
    app.directive('mapDirective',function(){
    return {
        templateUrl: 'map.html',
        restrict: 'EA',
        require: '?ngModel',
        scope:{
            myModel: '=ngModel'
        },
        link: function(scope , element, attrs , ngModel){
            var mapOptions;
            var googleMap;
            var searchMarker;
            var searchLatLng;
            scope.searchLocation = {
                latitude: 48.137273,
                longitude: 11.575251
            };
            ngModel.$render = function(){
                console.log("hhh");
                searchLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(scope.myModel.latitude, scope.myModel.longitude);

                mapOptions = {
                    center: searchLatLng,
                    zoom: 12,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };

                googleMap = new google.maps.Map(element[0],mapOptions);

                searchMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: searchLatLng,
                    map: googleMap,
                    draggable: true
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(searchMarker, 'dragend', function(){
                    scope.$apply(function(){
                        scope.myModel.latitude = searchMarker.getPosition().lat();
                        scope.myModel.longitude = searchMarker.getPosition().lng();
                    });
                }.bind(this));

            };

            scope.$watch('myModel', function(value){
                var myPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(scope.myModel.latitude, scope.myModel.longitude);
                searchMarker.setPosition(myPosition);
            }, true);
        }
    }
});
```

map.html:

```
<div>
    <div style="display: block; height: 200px; width: 100%; ">
    </div>
</div>
```

index.html:

```
<map-directive ng-model="testModel"></map-directive>
```

Actually , I got this error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined
```

How to solve it?

**EDITED:** 
I change my **maps.js**:

```
    app.directive('mapDirective',function(){
    return {
        templateUrl: '/app/user/ngApp/templates/libsView/templates/directives/map.html',
        restrict: 'EA',
        require: '?ngModel',
        scope:{
            myModel: '=ngModel'
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.searchLocation = {
                latitude: 48.137273,
                longitude: 11.575251
            };
        },
        link: function(scope , element, attrs , ngModel){

            var mapOptions;
            var googleMap;
            var searchMarker;
            var searchLatLng;

            ngModel.$render = function(){
                console.log("hhh");
                searchLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(scope.myModel.latitude, scope.myModel.longitude);

                mapOptions = {
                    center: searchLatLng,
                    zoom: 12,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };

                googleMap = new google.maps.Map(element[0],mapOptions);

                searchMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: searchLatLng,
                    map: googleMap,
                    draggable: true
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(searchMarker, 'dragend', function(){
                    scope.$apply(function(){
                        scope.myModel.latitude = searchMarker.getPosition().lat();
                        scope.myModel.longitude = searchMarker.getPosition().lng();
                    });
                }.bind(this));

            };

            scope.$watch('myModel', function(value){
                var myPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(scope.myModel.latitude, scope.myModel.longitude);
                searchMarker.setPosition(myPosition);
            }, true);
        }
    }
});
```

But it doesn't change.

Comment: please provide your controller's code\

Comment: what does testModel contains?

Comment: @HardikPatel nothing. what should I add?

Comment: myModel variable should contains latitude and longitude values.. which should be set from <map-directive ng-model="testModel"></map-directive>

Comment: @HardikPatel Put it as answer please

Answer (score 0):

myModel variable should contains latitude and longitude values. which should be set from

`<map-directive ng-model="testModel"></map-directive>`

You need to create a object as below in your controller and assign this object to directive as above html.

```
var testModel = {
    latitude:1.2323,
    longitude:2.3434
};
```

Comment: I choose <map-directive ng-model="35.6961,51.4231" ></map-directive> but I got this Error: [$parse:syntax]

Comment: Can you try this <map-directive ng-model="{latitude:35.6961,longitude:51.4231}" ></map-directive>

Comment: I tried this but I get this errors : angular.js: Error: [ngModel:nonassign] and angular.js Error: [$rootScope:infdig]

Comment: Can you create a plunkr.